# how to extract two strings from a line c++

Tags: c++, string, input, cin, getline

Suppose I have to read the following input:

```
dog ogday
cat atcay
pig igpay
froot ootfray
loops oopslay
str1 str2

atcay
ittenkay
oopslay
```

So I am unable to store all strings separately.
Heres a part of code I could come up with.

```
while(1)
{
    getline(cin,s);
    if(s.empty())
        break;
    else
        cout<<s<<endl;
}
```

So now I can store "dog ogday" in one string. But I want to store them in separate strings. Help please.(Thanks in advance :D)

Comment: Have you heard about `>>`? You usually learn about it before you get to `getline`.

Answer (score 1):

using `cin` to get two strings:

```
  string a,b;
  cin >> a >> b;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i=0;
while(i<9){
   getline(cin,s);
   if(s.empty())
     break;
   else
    cout<<s<<endl;
   i++;
  }
```

Not sure if this what you want, but I think it will let you store all 9 strings.

Comment: Magic number 9... Also, you should test your code first.

Answer (score 0):

This reads all the "words" (separated by spaces) separately.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    for (std::string s; std::getline(std::cin, s) && !(s.empty() || s.find_first_not_of(' ') == std::string::npos); )
    {
        std::istringstream stream{s};
        for (std::string str; stream >> str; std::cout << str << '\n');
    }
}
```